# Is it ok to delegate rendering in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I would like to know if there is any reason to avoid this pattern:

https://gist.github.com/hnordt/ec4a8ebabc8013ed15107cd133a3766f

I think React Native already does this, e.g. `<ListView renderRow />`

Comment: sorry, can you please explain the exact pattern in your words, but code.. Then I would love to check out the idea & code

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would avoid such an app-flow, where the Component is doing that much, like fetching and manipulating the data.

The main idea of React is `(data) => (view)`
a function (preferred a **pure function**), which returns the view..

Things like fetching data, changing the store, handling auth, should be moved to separate modules and run on some actions.

This way you are independent from the view layer, so you could put your api-stuff into angular, backbone, jquery, or even run it on the server.

I do not see any benefits of doing it this way, maybe you could write some unique selling points to your approach, would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Pattern is perfectly fine. Not for every I/O scenario, may be, but for the case when you know URL of resource which must be loaded *prior* to rendering. I would even improve it a bit.

[This parameter](https://gist.github.com/hnordt/ec4a8ebabc8013ed15107cd133a3766f#file-fetch-js-L7) in fact looks like stateless function React component. So, move its definition out of render, and define it as (stateless) component (as function).

Then, [this line](https://gist.github.com/hnordt/ec4a8ebabc8013ed15107cd133a3766f#file-fetch-js-L108) should be modified to consume every component, not just the function. Also, I would delay rendering up to the moment your AJAX is finished. Like this:

```
  return this.props.renderComponent({ ...this.state, fetch: this.fetch })
```

->

```
  return this.state.fetching ? <div/> : <this.props.renderComponent {...this.state } fetch={ this.fetch } />;
```

And remove try-catch. Not needed - now you components will be mounted only when data are ready, thus they can assume they have their data *synchronously*, and data flow is *declarative*. That's what we want, aren't we?

Which is the huge benefit of this pattern, and I don't see any rational reason it needs to be avoided.